# Template file not rendering result of form_for in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm recreating the steps in this rails tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUH1hewXnC0

If you seek to 7:35, you'll see a form_for block the user has created. When I add that code and view the page in a browser, the page renders fine but there's no html where the form should be -- not even empty tags. I've confirmed that it's not an issue with a missing migration or browser cacheing.

I've simplified the problem down, and now my show.html.erb template file is just:

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
    testing
    <% debugger %>
<%  end %>

<% for i in 0..5 %>
    <%= i %>
<% end %>
```

(The second block is just to make sure the rendering is working)

The rendered html is:

```
... bunch of header stuff here ...
<body>

0
1
2
3
4
5

</body>
</html>
```

"testing" is not getting rendered as part of the html.

I put in that debugger line so I could use the debugger gem with rails server --debugger . Using that gets me to this point:

```
[196, 205] in /Users/Ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb
   196            buf = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new
   197            buf.force_encoding(output_buffer.encoding) if output_buffer
   198          end
   199          self.output_buffer, old_buffer = buf, output_buffer
   200          yield
=> 201          output_buffer
   202        ensure
   203          self.output_buffer = old_buffer
   204        end
   205  
(rdb:48) p output_buffer
"    testing\n"
```

So, the form_for is getting executed, but not getting delivered all the way through to the output html somehow. (that's why I'm not bothering to show you that I'm correctly initializing @post.)

I can't find any mention of similar problems online, but I'm probably just not looking for the right things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're missing the `=` sign: `<%= form_for @post do |f| %>`

Comment: did this change at some point in rails? this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG_mvp8u4cI doesn't use an equals sign, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @BenjaminWheeler It was introduced with Rails 3.
Source: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out as soon as I finished writing question (always seems to happen on stackoverflow!)

On the form_for line, <% should instead be <%= .

I suppose that changed at some point in rails?

Comment: How is this different than @Andrei's answer?

Comment: looks like he and i posted answers at the same time